# set namespace for all db operations

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to set the namespace for all DB operations for the Google App Engine in python, but i can't get it done.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
""" Set Google namespace """
if user:
    namespace = thisUser.namespace
    namespace_manager.set_namespace(namespace)
""" End Google namespace """

#Then i have all sorts of classes:

class MainPage(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        #code with DB operations like get and put...

class MainPage2(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        #code with DB operations like get and put...

class MainPage3(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        #code with DB operations like get and put...

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ ... ], debug=True, config=webapp2_config)
```

The problem with this is, is that in the classes all DB operations are still done on the default namespace (so as if no namespace is set). Eventhough i set the namespace in the very top of my code.

When i print the variable "namespace", which i also set in the top of the code, then i do get to see the namespace that i wish to use.

But it looks like Google App Engine somewhere resets the namespace to empty before running the code in the classes.

So now i'm wondering if there's a good way to set the namespace once somewhere.

Currently i set it like this in all "def's":

```
class MainPage(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        namespace_manager.set_namespace(namespace)

        #code with DB operations like get and put...

class MainPage(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        namespace_manager.set_namespace(namespace)

        #code with DB operations like get and put...

etc...
```

It's just not a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [write a middleware](http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/03/18/simple-wsgi-middleware-app-engine.html) that will intercept the request and will set the namespace according to your app logic.

Comment: Nice, got it working. There's one thing i changed though. The article says i have to return: **return resp(environ, start_response)** But that gave me a error 500. So now i'm using: **return self.app(environ, start_response)** instead, which works for me.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to add a hook. Something like that should be works.

```
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map

NAMESPACE_NAME = 'noname'
def namespace_call(service, call, request, response):
    if hasattr(request, 'set_name_space'):
        request.set_name_space(NAMESPACE_NAME)
apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetPreCallHooks().Append(
    'datastore-hooks', namespace_call, 'datastore_v3')
```

You can add it in your `main.py` or `appengine_config.py`. By this way the hook is configured during the loading of the instances and keeps his state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use appconfig.py and define namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request()

Have a read of https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy see the first section of "Setting the Current Namespace"

Comment: It's a good solution, but by this way you add a namespace for all services. I don't know if it what he wants.

Comment: yep, though you could choose not to set the namespace depending on some logic.  However if namespaces differed because of the type of request, then it might be better to make the namespace choice specific to handlers.